# rendr-handlebars with gulp

Tags: gulp, handlebars.js, rendr

I'm trying to use gulp as the compiler for my rendr app, but I'm running into the issue of

```
500 TypeError: template is not a function
   at module.exports.Backbone.View.extend.getInnerHtml (/home/longjeongs/thinksquareio.github.io/node_modules/rendr/shared/base/view.js:191:12)
   at module.exports.Backbone.View.extend.getHtml (/home/longjeongs/thinksquareio.github.io/node_modules/rendr/shared/base/view.js:198:21)
   at ViewEngine.getViewHtml (/home/longjeongs/thinksquareio.github.io/node_modules/rendr/server/viewEngine.js:75:15)
   at ViewEngine.render (/home/longjeongs/thinksquareio.github.io/node_modules/rendr/server/viewEngine.js:22:16)
   at View.render (/home/longjeongs/thinksquareio.github.io/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:126:8)
   at tryRender (/home/longjeongs/thinksquareio.github.io/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:639:10)
   at EventEmitter.render (/home/longjeongs/thinksquareio.github.io/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:591:3)
   at ServerResponse.render (/home/longjeongs/thinksquareio.github.io/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
   at /home/longjeongs/thinksquareio.github.io/node_modules/rendr/server/router.js:87:11
   at Object.module.exports.create (/home/longjeongs/thinksquareio.github.io/app/controllers/users_controller.js:5:5)
```

I couldn't find any examples of compiling `rendr-handlebars` and `handlebars` with gulp anywhere and thought I will try getting some help here.

I have read elsewhere that this is caused by different compiler handlebars and client handlebars version, but I believe that I have the correct ones installed. I have these dependencies installed

```
│ ├─┬ handlebars@2.0.0
├─┬ gulp-handlebars@3.0.1
├─┬ handlebars@2.0.0
├── rendr-handlebars@2.0.1
```

and my `compiledTempaltes.js` file shows `"compiler":[6,">= 2.0.0-beta.1"]`. My gulp task for handlebars does the following;

```
gulp.task('handlebars:compile', function () {

    return gulp.src('./app/templates/**/[!__]*.hbs')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(handlebars({ wrapped : true, handlebars: require('handlebars') }))
        .pipe(wrap('templates["<%= file.relative.replace(/\\\\/g, "/").replace(/.js$/, "") %>"] = <%= file.contents %>;\n'))
        .pipe(concat('compiledTemplates.js'))
        .pipe(wrap('module.exports = function(Handlebars){\ntemplates = {};\n<%= contents %>\nreturn templates \n};'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/templates/'));
});
```

I've tried installing different versions of handlebars, rendr-handlebars, and gulp-handlebars without much luck, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using gulp with my rendr project... I made a sample app that you can check out... https://github.com/jaredrada/rendrjs-demo

There are a few problems with the browser sync which I've fixed locally- so if you copy the entire gulp setup that portion will not work. I will push my edits to the github repo.

Comment: Would be nice to add this to Rendr examples

Comment: just for the down vote i wont bother to fix it. @smohadjer